# Filter 2 struct/ arrays by mapping by specific

Tags: arrays, json, uitableview, swift3

Im a new user using swift 3 and xcode 8.3. Currently facing a problem to filter 2 array/struc where in console output as below:

```
A_List : Optional([117, 115, 18])

B_List : Optional([{
    URL = "169.jpeg";
    categories = "A";
    description = "description XXX";
    height = 128;
    id = 1;
    likes = "1.00";
    name = "Cake - Baked";
    price = "13.78";
    width = 128;
}, {
    URL = "1622.jpeg";
    categories = "A";
    description = "Baked till golden";
    height = 128;
    id = 15;
    likes = "1.00";
    name = "Croissant";
    price = "3.71";
    width = 128;
}, {
    URL = "11.jpeg";
    categories = "A";
    description = "description Crispy.";
    height = 128;
    id = 18;
    likes = "1.00";
    name = "Plain";
    price = "2.65";
    width = 128;
}, {
    URL = "1622.jpeg";
    categories = "A";
    description = "A ";
    height = 128;
    id = 103;
    likes = "1.00";
    name = "America Pie";
    price = "2.12";
    width = 128;
}, {
    URL = "11.jpeg";
    categories = "B";
    description = "Puff";
    height = 128;
    id = 115;
    likes = "1.00";
    name = "Puff";
    price = "2.12";
    width = 128;
}, {
    URL = "168.jpeg";
    categories = "C";
    description = "description YYY";
    height = 128;
    id = 117;
    likes = "1.00";
    name = "Normal";
    price = "3.18";
    width = 128;
}])
```

I want to return **B_List full info** as `var filtered_List = [AnyObject]()` where only contains of A_List id number `117, 115, and 18` which look like as below:

```
filtered_List : Optional([{
        URL = "11.jpeg";
        categories = "A";
        description = "description Crispy.";
        height = 128;
        id = 18;
        likes = "1.00";
        name = "Plain";
        price = "2.65";
        width = 128;
    }, {
        URL = "11.jpeg";
        categories = "B";
        description = "Puff";
        height = 128;
        id = 115;
        likes = "1.00";
        name = "Mini Puff";
        price = "2.12";
        width = 128;
    }, {
        URL = "168.jpeg";
        categories = "C";
        description = "description YYY";
        height = 128;
        id = 117;
        likes = "1.00";
        name = "Normal";
        price = "3.18";
        width = 128;
    }])
```

I have tried few code and read tutorial in youtube, but unfortunately did not find any solution and it limited to swift2 sample.

Currently, my code tried as below:

```
var filtered_List = [AnyObject]()
let fullrList = B_List?.map{$0["id"] as! String}.map{_ in A_List}
filtered_List.append(fullrList as AnyObject )
print("result :\(filtered_List)")
```

Very Appreciated if someone expert can guide or give your solution here.

Comment: Swift convention is to use lowerCamelCase for variable names, not snake_case, and definitely not Upper_snake_case. Also, your names "A list", "B list", convey absolutely no information about their content. I strongly advise you to give better names

Comment: @Peterhdd do **not** use code formatting for things that aren't code like versions or names of technologies [see this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for your kindness advise. Yes, I accept your comment and will do it better in my code.

Comment: @Peterhdd thanks for the correction. Appreciated.

Comment: @jmattheis, big thanks to your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your desired IDs in a Set, rather than an Array. You're just need a simple `filter` operation:

```
let desiredIds: Set = [117, 115, 18]

B_List.filter{ $0["id"].map{ desiredIds.contains($0) } ?? false } as [AnyObject]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works!. Anyway how do I set A_List as desiredIds? Since A_List will change.  Error show "Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to specified type "Set".

Comment: @D_9268 Run it through the `Set` initializer. (e.g. `Set(someArray)`). Why is `A_List` of type `[AnyObject]`, and not `[Int]`?

Comment: Thanks got it. The A_List was filter from JSON format by other program. And end up i found that all information in both A/B_List is in String. Therefore, I have to make sure "id" map with string too.

Comment: @D_9268 Whenever you're working with JSON, make sure you get out of the world of `Any`, `AnyObject`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `[String: Any]`, etc. You want to get to type-safe land as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks for your advise and point out my weakness! I will go through more tutorials about handling JSON stuff in Swift.

Comment: @D_9268 It's really about JSON, it's about avoiding loosely typed data. JSON is just one of the many things that can force you to deal with loosely typed data, but SQL, XML, and many other things will need that too. It's just important you safely check the types as soon as possible, and convert to strongly typed data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who reply this topic specially to @Alexander. Here my solutions to share that may not the perfect one as others.

```
var resultAnyObject = [AnyObject]()
var aListIds = [String]()

for i in A_List! {
    aListIds.append(i as! String)
}

//@Alexander : thanks for code below:
let desiredIds = aListIds

let fullList = B_List?.filter{ $0["id"].map{desiredIds.contains($0 as! String) } ?? false };

resultAnyObject.append(fullList as AnyObject)

print("Result of filtered_List :\(resultAnyObject)")
```

Comment: you just need `A_List as [String]`, or perhaps `map`. Avoid looping with repeated `append` calls